# update statement with FROM and ctids

Tags: postgresql

I have an update statement of the following (simplified) form:

```
     UPDATE changes.table1 a
        SET checked_out_at = a.checked_out_at
       FROM unified.view2 b
      WHERE a.ctid = '(4,48)'
        AND b.some_pkey = a.some_pkey
  RETURNING *;
```

This statement will just fail to update. I see `0 rows` and `UPDATE 0` when I run it. But if I modify it by dropping the joined table, the update will go through (just once, the ctid changes after all, and I'd need to find the new one):

```
     UPDATE changes.table1 a
        SET checked_out_at = a.checked_out_at
      WHERE a.ctid = '(4,48)'
  RETURNING *;
```

Unfortunately, I need the joined table for some of the data in the RETURNING clause.

Why are these two features incompatible? Do the joined rows somehow have ctids different from the single table? I know that I don't have a proper understanding of all the low-level system columns, but this still seems rather straight forward. Can this or something similar be made to work?

Comment: Where are you getting the `ctid` from?

Comment: Are you sure that `unified.view2` actually contains the row of interest? If the condition would not match anything, it would explain why no rows are updated - `UPDATE FROM` builds the cartesian product after all

Comment: Why are you using `ctid` at all?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver So that I can do a limit clause. update doesn't have a native limit, so I'm doing "select ctid from table1 where whatever limit 10" or something like that. Wasn't relevant to the problem.

Comment: Works for me.  What version are you using?

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I've confirmed. The row of interest is there. I just wish I could organize it so that those columns were in table1, and I wouldn't need the FROM at all, but that causes other sorts of problems.

Comment: @jjanes 15 something. Offhand I don't remember what minor version, will get it in the morning if it's important.

Comment: It works for me with v15.3.  I doubt the minor version matters, I suspect you are just doing something wrong.

Comment: @jjanes I don't disagree with you. I just don't see what it is I'm missing or messing up.

Comment: @JohnO  I don't see the problem either. But I suspect your real query is not exactly what you show here (for example, your SET seems pointless as written and unified.view2 seems like an unlikely name, so maybe some transcription problem).  Could you give us the CREATE statements for all the involved tables?

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to limit the number of rows that get updated, consider using a subquery as follows:

```
UPDATE changes.table1 a
   SET checked_out_at = a.checked_out_at
  FROM (SELECT c.ctid AS original_ctid, b.*
          FROM changes.table1 c
          JOIN unified.view2 b
            ON b.some_pkey = a.some_pkey
         LIMIT 10) d
 WHERE a.ctid = d.original_ctid
RETURNING *;
```

This will limit the number of updated rows while avoiding an extra table or index scan since a TID scan will be used to find the rows to be updated. It also eliminates the need to determine CTIDs in separate queries.

Comment: Thank you. I will get a chance to try this tomorrow. It does indeed look like a cleaner construction of what I intend.